# RandomAccessFile - Unwritten bytes

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

I use `java.io.RandomAccessFile` to open a file and write few entries in the same at random locations. When I read the file back, is it guaranteed that unwritten bytes in that file *(that may be in between two locations which were written earlier)* are returned as **0**?